# Javascript to prevent clickjacking

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, runtime-error, clickjacking

I have this Javascript snippet in my application to prevent clickjacking:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var style = document.createElement('style');
     style.type = "text/css";
     style.id = "antiClickjack";
     style.innerHTML = "body{display:none !important;}";
     document.head.appendChild(style);

     if (self === top) {
         var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
         antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
     } else {
         top.location = self.location;
     }
</script>
```

Basically, it creates a style element (CSS on the fly) to hide the body of the current page by default. Then, *if it doesn't* detect clickjacking, it deletes it. So, doing it this way, everyone who doesn't have Javascript can see the page too (although they won't be protected from clickjacking).

It works for every browser except for Internet Explorer, which throws a **Unknown runtime error** exception. Does someone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I've always loved "unknown runtime error".  It's like it's so confused that it can't even tell you what happened.

Comment: i have found on most occasions "unknown runtime error", will be on the next line, to where the error is line number shows, that why when developing code its good to use multiple lines for each statement, as you do

Comment: You can see my discussion that contains pretty good frame buster with this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349628/busting-a-tough-frame-killer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the content of a `<style>` element via `innerHTML`.  I think the correct property name is `cssText` but I'll have to check MSDN.

*edit* — yup that's it.

Thus your code can do this:

```
 var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.type = "text/css";
 style.id = "antiClickjack";
 if ('cssText' in style)
   style.cssText = "body{display:none !important;}";
 else
   style.innerHTML = "body{display:none !important;}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I tried both of your suggestions but I'm still getting a "unknown runtime error" error. I guess the problem must be somewhere else..

Comment: Sorry, I now recieve a DIFFERENT error (also, only in IE). "document.head" is null or not an object

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);` instead. Also, make sure you do that when there's actually a complete `<head>` element - it might not work so well from *inside* the `<head>` (not sure; never tried it).

Comment: It worked! And from inside the <head> element. So I guess the "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);" was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the document HEAD element, add the following:

```
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   if (self === top) {
       var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
       antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
   } else {
       top.location = self.location;
   }
</script>
```