# Busting a tough FRAME killer

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame, penetration-testing, clickjacking

I've been trying to break this up for a few hours now but with no success... I am pretty desperate now :(

I am doing penetration testing for a company and I need to bypass this frame killer JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
if (top != self) {
    try {
        if (parent != top) {
            throw 1;
        }
        var disallowed = ['XXXXXXX.com'];
        var href = top.location.href.toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < disallowed.length; i++) {
            if (href.indexOf(disallowed[i]) >= 0) {
                throw 1;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = '';
        } catch (e) { /* IE */
            var htmlEl = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
            htmlEl.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);
            var el = document.createElement('head');
            htmlEl.appendChild(el);
        }
        window.document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="top.location.href=window.location.href" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/img/XXXXXX.gif" style="border:0px;" /><br />Go to XXXXXXX.com</a>';
    }
}

/* ]]> */</script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Bro, you need to indent that code. I cant read that

Comment: Ohh sorry... I thought it will auto indent.
I see now that Pointy did it for me.

Thank you!

Comment: They use a disallowed list and not an allowed list?  That doesn't seem very secure. (Do you have permission to be posting this?  A penetration test doesn't usually include sharing the code on the net)

Comment: I have changed the code a little and deleted their names.
anyway, similar code is published on the internet as a solution for ClickJacking, they just modified it a little. So there is nothing secret here.

Comment: The [sandbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498) and [security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717126/) attributes can prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following:

- IP Address instead of domain name to bypass the disallowed list
- [X-Frame-Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx)
- [HTML5 sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx)

> If the body element's node document's browsing context is a nested browsing context, and the browsing context container of that nested browsing context is a frame or iframe element, then the container frame element of the body element is that frame or iframe element. Otherwise, there is no container frame element.
>
> The above requirements imply that a page can change the margins of another page (including one from another origin) using, for example, an iframe. This is potentially a security risk, as it might in some cases allow an attack to contrive a situation in which a page is rendered not as the author intended, possibly for the purposes of phishing or otherwise misleading the user.

**References**

- [HTML5 Specification, Section 10: Rendering](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html)

Comment: Of the above X-Frame-Options is well accepted as a defense against Clickjacking attempts. Please check the limitation on this option at  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet. Almost all current versions of the Browsers support this option. This is your best option.